# Do azure provide/offer any api or any way from which i can add custom domain to my app service?

Tags: c#, azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

I have my domain on **namecheap** and website on azure app service. I need to know if azure provide any **api or any method** by which i can add custom domain to my app service (where my website is) by not **going on portal**  by doing some code. My website is on c#, so if c# provide any such sdk's or something where i can achieve this thing will be great

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are intending here, in my opinion the custom domains need to be configured on the namecheap side not the azure side, but just in case I am wrong have a look at these

https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/app-service-web/web-sites-custom-domain-name.md

https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/dns/dns-web-sites-custom-domain.md

Comment: yes custom domain will be created and configured in namecheap side but still i have to add Custom domain in azure.